# Looking for CRS for NAD 83 UTM Zone 30N

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm curious as to why the UTM zones are incomplete for NAD 83 in QGIS?  I have a WGS84 shapefile that I would like to project to NAD83 UTM Zone 30N but can't find it in the QGIS CRS list.

I see how one could create a custom coordinate system but the cut and paste I did of proj.4 code for zone 15 (simply changed it to 30) didn't work.

Thanks for pointing me to proper proj.4 code or how to project this shapefile from the UK.

Comment: Just a  note: UK data uses British National Grid (OSGB36) in most cases where the data comes from the Ordnance Survey. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/

Comment: To follow up on @Mapperz comment.  If you are using data from the UK, you shouldn't use a UTM grid based on the NAD 83 datum, as that stands for North American Datum, and is calibrated for data located in North America.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is well defined as UTM 30 is outside the US and the rest of us don't use NAD83 as a datum. [Spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=utm%2030n&srtext=Search) provides a list of possible datums you could chose.